# Update an activity after a dialog is dismissed

Tags: java, android

In my main activity I have an alert that allows users to edit a setting.  Once the user selects that setting and it's dismissed I want to call the onCreate() method to refresh the main activity to be updated with the new settings but I'm not sure how to call the main activity from inside the onClick() function.

The dialog is created in a method in the main activity.  I could also call a refresh() method I've created inside my class to update everything but that has the same issue of calling a non-static method from a static context.

Comment: What do you want to update? Do you really need to restart the activity? Usually only needed when you change a theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
MainActivity.recreate();
```

The activity will be recreated with new instance so It will recall `onCreate` again as you needed. It is supported for API 11 or higher.

For APIs lower than 11 use this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.